# PostLoginRedirectUri as PostLogoutRedirectUris in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

Is there a PostLoginRedirectUri as there is PostLogoutRedirectUris in IdentityServer4?

I basically want to Redirect the user to a Controller/Action which is in another web application if the RedirectUri is null during Login.

Thanks!
Jay

Comment: If redirect_uri is null, identityserver gives an error. I couldn't understand 
in which situations do you need PostLoginRedirectUri on identityserver side . If you need to redirect user to a url after login in some conditions, this should be on the client app side.

Comment: My landing page is the Login view of my identityServer web app. So what this means is that once the Login action method gets hit, it will not have a value for redirectUri.

In such a scenario, once the user is Authenticated successfully, I want the user to be redirected to a page on a different web app which is configured to be used with the identityServer web app.